# Which is better SAVE BUTTON or SAVE ON EDIT in wpf entity framework with mvvm

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I have one data entry form where I have text boxes for entering data and buttons for firing actions.and I have on listview  for displaying the the records from Data base..and the listview is bound with Prospects( observable collection).listview 's selected items are bound with text boxes where I enter entries  .after entering the data in the text boxes I just click on Add button which fires and fill the observable collection and when I click the save button the new entry will be saved in to data base :By add button and save button code:
https://www.lynda.com/course-tutorials/Learning-JIRA-Software/545920-2.html?srchtrk=index%3a3%0alinktypeid%3a2%0aq%3aJIRA%0apage%3a1%0as%3arelevance%0asa%3atrue%0aproducttypeid%3a2
https://www.lynda.com/Business-Project-Management-tutorials/Agile-Project-Management/122428-2.html

Comment: Can you copy the code of the Edit button, please? I mean the command in the ViewModel

Comment: in edit button click  I just enabling the text boxes control so that user can enter in the text boxes:public void Edit()
        { ManageControls(false); }

Comment: Can you copy then the XAML code for those textboxes? Are they binding to SelectedPerson.FirstName, etc...? If so, can you copy SelectedPerson code too, please?

Comment: <Button Name="btnEdit" Command="{Binding Commands.Edit}"
              Content="_Edit"
        Width="auto" Margin="5,0,5,0" Padding="10,0,10,0" />

Comment: Please, update the question with ALL related code. I need to see the XAML and the SelectedPerson code to know why it is saving changes on edit. Thank you

Comment: The ViewModel too, please... :)

Comment: For validation reasons, you should definitely save an entity once. Changing one property may temporarily invalidate another property until that has been edited.

Comment: Comic. Sans. No.

Comment: Validations on Edit and Save Once during Button click. Think of the traffic you generate if you save to Database on every key press.